# recipe also produces -native output that needs packaging

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have a recipe which successfully invokes a legacy build command to cross-compile a target.

As a side effect it produces some custom native tools that are used in the build.

I want to reap those tools into a `-tools-native` package to allow other recipes to depend the main package to access the artifacts, and use the `-tools-native` package to further process those artifacts.

I can build such a native package as simply as adding:

```
PROVIDES = "${PN} ${PN}-tools-native"
SYSROOT_DIRS += "/"
PACKAGES += "${PN}-tools-native"
FILES_${PN}-tools-native += "/native-bin/*"
```

and having the install section install the native tools to /native-bin/

but yet it somehow isn't a real native package, and when `DEPENDS`'d by an additional recipe the `native-bin artifacts are installed in`recipe-sysroot`instead of`recipe-sysroot-native`

I also have to install the tools 0644 or bitbake tries to strip them (and fails, as they are native build).

Because the native tools are already generated by the legacy build commands, I don't need to actually invoke as a `-native` recipe variant.

It's a long process, I don't want to run it twice, either.

Currently I work around it by having the other recipes `DEPEND` on `recipe-native-tools` and fixup the permissions and PATH

But what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can play with the overrides (`class-target`, `class-native`) and `BBCLASSEXTEND` and pick what you want to install or ignore in each case.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion @danlor, but won't that involve invoking the recipe twice? which I want to avoid.

Comment: Yes...but I'm afraid there's no other way to go (well, alternatively, you can write separated recipes for target and host, stating `inherit native` in the latter...).

Comment: Thanks @dnalor, given Richard's answer below, I'll try working along your lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally handled by separate recipes. There is no mechanism to share native binaries from target recipes as their task hashes have the wrong kinds of information in them (they change depending on the target architecture).

Target recipes don't install their bindir/sbindir into the sysroot since we can't run them and as you mention, they're the wrong architecture so they confuse strip and so on.

You could try having a native recipe which depended upon this target recipe and which installs the binaries saved by the target recipe somewhere into its ${D} at do_install. That may well give some warnings since in general native recipes shouldn't depend on target recipes but is probably your best option if you can't build twice.

Comment: clear answer - thanks. I'll try working with @danlor's suggestion with the aim to separate the building of the native tools. If I can get workspace sharing it would be even simpler.