# Yocto rust recipe also produces -native output that needs packaging

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I tried this approach on hardknott but I couldn't get it to work [recipe also produces -native output that needs packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971910/recipe-also-produces-native-output-that-needs-packaging)

It is a rust recipe that generates an x86_64 app which I would like to package the right way in sdk, so that it can be used.

I can separate the main package to -native-bin, and I see it in the recipe-sysroot, but I can't get it to populate the recipe-sysroot of the workdir of the file when building the -native-helper recipe. And I suspect the reason is that I get an error that the main recipe for x86_64 can't be found?

```
ERROR: Manifest xxxxxx.populate_sysroot not found in vs_imx8mp cortexa53 armv8a-crc armv8a aarch64 allarch x86_64_x86_64-nativesdk (variant '')?
```

So any helpful information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacked like this:

Recipe.bb:

```
do_install_append() {
    # Set permision without run flag so that it doesn't fail on checks
    chmod 644 ${D}/usr/bin/@RECIPE@-compiler
}

# @RECIPE@ generates a compiler during the target generation step
#separate this to the -native-bin package, and skip the ARCH checks
#also in the image file for stations_sdk move the app to right dir and add execute flag
PACKAGES_prepend = "${PN}-native-bin "
PROVIDES_prepend = "${PN}-native-bin "
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}-native-bin = "arch"
FILES_${PN}-native-bin = "/usr/bin/@RECIPE@-compiler"

SYSROOT_DIRS += "/"
```

Image.bb:

```
# @RECIPE@ produces a compiler that is produced as a part of the target generation
#so we use the recipe and hack it to supply the -compiler as part of the 
#host binaries
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " @RECIPE@-native-bin"

do_fix_@RECIPE@() {
    mv ${SDK_OUTPUT}/${SDKTARGETSYSROOT}/usr/bin/@RECIPE@-compiler ${SDK_OUTPUT}/${SDKPATHNATIVE}/usr/bin/@RECIPE@-compiler
    chmod 755 ${SDK_OUTPUT}/${SDKPATHNATIVE}/usr/bin/@RECIPE@-compiler
}

SDK_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND_prepend = "do_fix_@RECIPE@; "
```

This produces at the end the binary in the right directory